# ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? en Codespaces

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, devops

¡Hola a todos!

Estoy tratando de configurar un container de .Net core y Docker en Codespaces. Asi que use la siguiente configuracion:

devcontainer.json

```
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/dotnet
{
    "name": "C# (.NET)",
    // Or use a Dockerfile or Docker Compose file. More info: https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile
    "build": { "dockerfile": "Dockerfile" },
    

    // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
    // "features": {},

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
     "forwardPorts": [3000, 5432],
     "portsAttributes": {
            "5001": {
                "protocol": "https"
            }
     },

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    // "postCreateCommand": "dotnet restore",

    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    "customizations": {
        // Configure properties specific to VS Code.
        "vscode": {
          // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
          "extensions": [
            "streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker",
            "docsmsft.docs-authoring-pack",
            "donjayamanne.githistory",
            "eamodio.gitlens",
            "editorconfig.editorconfig",
            "github.vscode-pull-request-github",
            "jongrant.csharpsortusings",
            "k--kato.docomment",
            "kreativ-software.csharpextensions",
            "mhutchie.git-graph",
            "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
            "ms-vscode.powershell",
            "ms-vscode.vscode-node-azure-pack",
            "ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare",
            "visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode",
            "yzhang.markdown-all-in-one"
        ]
        }
      }

    // Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
    // "remoteUser": "root"
}
```

Y este es el Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0

WORKDIR /workspaces/.net-core-app

COPY . .

RUN bash ./setup.sh
```

Y por ultimo aca estan todas las dependencias del proyecto alojadas en `setup.sh`:

```
## Update and install some things we should probably have
apt-get update
apt-get install -y \
  curl \
  git \
  gnupg2 \
  jq \
  sudo \
  zsh

## Instsall nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash


## Install Docker CLI
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | bash

## Update to the latest PowerShell
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/master/tools/install-powershell.sh | bash

## Install Azure Functions Core Tools v3
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
apt-get update
apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools-3

## Enable local HTTPS
dotnet dev-certs https --trust

## Setup and install oh-my-zsh
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
cp -R /root/.oh-my-zsh /home/$USERNAME
cp /root/.zshrc /home/$USERNAME
sed -i -e "s/\/root\/.oh-my-zsh/\/home\/$USERNAME\/.oh-my-zsh/g" /home/$USERNAME/.zshrc
chown -R $USER_UID:$USER_GID /home/$USERNAME/.oh-my-zsh /home/$USERNAME/.zshrc
```

Cabe destacar que todos los features se instalaron correctamente, pero cuando uso el comando `Docker build -t Dockerfile` para construir la imagen, me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Entonces utilice el comando `sudo docker service start` y me devuelve `Starting Docker: docker.` pero el problema anterior persiste.

Cabe destacar que esto lo estoy haciendo en Github codespaces, y no se si halla alguna configuracion que estoy omitiendo.

De todos modos, si alguien me puede ayudar estare agradecido

Comment: Probaste con sudo? `sudo docker build -t Dockerfile`

Comment: Si, y me sigue arrojando el mismo error.